# ConnectionString a una clase c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Intento llenar un combobox desde un Stored Procedure, al intentar conectar desde un ConnectrionString me marcar error

```
public class CFDI
    {
        string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnn))
        {

        }   
    }
```

es la misma linea de code que uso en el login

```
public void logins()
        {
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
```

esta es la cadena en el archivo app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="prueba" connectionString="Data Source=CHRISTIAN;Initial Catalog=QualitzPalmiss;User ID=sa;Password=Montecristo1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="produccion" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER-04\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=QualitzPalmiss;User ID=sa;Password=PALMISS"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que dice el mensaje de error ?

Comment: donde ubiscas el app.config? o sea en cual proyecto

Comment: @LeandroTuttini son varios ... te dejo una imagen https://ibb.co/6tn3gmc

Comment: Esta dentro del mismo proyecto Facturas2019

Comment: Si no muestras el error no podremos ayudarte

Comment: El codigo es ese que mostras? tenes el codigo directamente dentro de la clase? no dentro de una funcion?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por la ayuda.. pero escribio el codigo directamente en la clase, no en un metodo...

Comment: @gbianchi si exacto, no lo habia observado hasta que puso la imagen, esa es la respuesta que hay que darle para ayudarlo, que defina la funcionalidad en un metodo y no directo en la clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora con la imagen veo el problema, resulta que estas desarrollando a nivel del la `class` en lugar de hacerlo dentro de un `metodo` o `funcion`

Lo que tinees que hacer es poner ese codigo en una funcion, algo como ser

```
public class CFDI
{
    public void NombreMetodo()
    {
        string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnn))
        {

        }  
    }       
}
```

alli puse un `NombreMetodo()` porque no se que nombre quieres darle pero creo que sirve a modo de ejemplo

El otro codigo que nos muestras seguro funciona porque tu metodo se llama `logins()`

Si quieres olo retornar el connstrin string podrias usar

```
public class ConnStringHelper
{
    public static string GetProduccion()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Vengaaaaa que llevaba todo el dia en esto ... gracias!, aunque no se si deberia llamar asi a las conexiones no seria mejor poner el ConnectionString en una clase y de ahi instanciar en donde la quiera usar?

Comment: no, el connection string es correcto definirlo en el app.config y tomarlo desde alli donde lo necesites. Si por alguna razon quieres anstraer las lineas del ConfigurationManager crear una clase que retorne el string, como en el ejmplo que agregue en la respuesta